# How to increase deserialization speed?

Tags: c#, performance, serialization, binaryformatter

Serializing/deserializing with BinaryFormatter, resulting serialized file is ~80MB in size. The deserialization takes a few minutes. How could I improve on this? Here's the deserialization code:

```
    public static Universe DeserializeFromFile(string filepath)
    {
        Universe universe = null;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        try
        {
            universe = (Universe)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }

        return universe;
    }
```

Maybe read all to memory prior to deserializing or use some other serialization technique?

Answer (score 2):

Try `UnsafeDeserialize`. It is said to improve speed.

Comment: UnsafeDeserialize 460138 ms, Deserialize 459967 ms.. ie. Deserialize was actually faster! I set the headers with the UnsafeDeserialize to null, is this perhaps the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but stumbled upon a solution that improved my deserialization speed substantially.  This is useful if you have large sets of data.

Upgrade your target framework to 4.7.1+ and enable the following switch in your app.config.

```
<runtime>
    <!-- Use this switch to make BinaryFormatter fast with large object graphs starting with .NET 4.7.2 -->
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Runtime.Serialization.UseNewMaxArraySize=true" />
</runtime>
```

Sources:
[BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20569)
[AppContextSwitchOverrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element)

Comment: In my case, this slows down serialization speed.

Comment: Worked a treat for my application, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092020/xml-vs-binary-performance-for-serialization-deserialization).

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file into a memory stream first in one go, then deserialize using the memory stream.

Comment: If that makes things better rather than worse, then the serialization format sucks. Why do an I/O bound task *followed by* a CPU-bound task when you could do both, interleaved?

Answer (score 0):

How complex is the data? If it is an object *tree* (rather than a full *graph*), then you might get some interesting results from trying [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). It is *generally* pretty easy to fit onto existing classes, and is generally much smaller, faster, and less brittle (you can change the object model without trashing the data).

Disclosure: I'm the author, so might be biased - but it really isn't terrible... I'd happily lend some* time to help you try it, though.

*=within reason

Answer (score -1):

Implement ISerializable in the Universe class