# Java: Serialization/ Deserialization to/from XML instead of binary

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a complex set of data models that currently implement `java.io.Serializable`, and I have successfully serialized and deserialized them with `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

However, the result are binary files (as expected), and I was wondering if Java supports serialization and deserialization in the same manner to a non-binary format, such as XML.

---

I see that C# has this feature: [XML vs Binary performance for Serialization/Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092020/xml-vs-binary-performance-for-serialization-deserialization).

Performance speed/ efficiency is not a consideration in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Java has it and it's called **XML Encoding**. Check it out [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/)!

The approach is quite similar to the normal serialization..

Answer (score 5):

Further, I would suggest you to look at [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) and [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) frameworks. I found both good. You can choose to go with either one, or may be XmlEncoder as suggested by Jack.

Comment: I'm chiming in for XStream too.

Comment: Simple if far more performant that XStream, at worst case its 2x faster. Also, for very large object graphs Simple beats Java object serialization.